# Is there a way to inject behavior to csrss.exe and modify/enhance windows console?

Tags: windows, console, console-application

I'm aware of Console2 and similar solutions, but I would really like to enhance every console window in my system. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to inject code into csrss.exe. Is it a good idea? NO!

What exactly do you want to enhance?

The only thing I can think of is to handle Ctrl+C

Non-Square selections would also be nice but I don't think that's possible, even with injection.

Comment: Basically, I was sort of thinking on the actual console to be replaced by something else, a different window class. I know it's not trivial, and completely agree it's not a good idea but I still want to do it. It's not like I'll be testing this in production environments.

My idea is: whenever csrss.exe invokes a new console, I would intercept the call and return the injected code.

In other words, I want this: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/ but need some piggybacking by someone that could point me to actual code. Please let me know your comments, I'm very interested.

Comment: I'd like to enhance the title bar to be a standard windows one. I'd like cut and paste to work in a more standard way. I'd like the window width to be resizable by dragging. I'd like it to be much faster when I set the history buffer to be 5000 lines. I'd like to change the default font, window and history buffer size. I'd like page-up and page-down to scroll the window. And many other things...